# Change alt/cmd preference fedora22

Tags: fedora, gnome, keyboard-layout, macintosh

How do I switch my <kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys so that Fedora22 will behave like an OSX keyboard?

I've found references concerning [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368437/how-do-i-remap-my-ubuntu-keyboard-shortcuts-to-match-osx) but they don't directly appear to work the same.

Gnome's documentation on standard shortcuts is [missing](https://developer.gnome.org/hig/stable/input-keyboard.html.en#standard-shortcuts).

Fedora's keyboard settings just seem to lock my computer until I delete any change in keyboard settings.

It's a duplicate of this [issue](https://superuser.com/questions/170060/use-apple-keyboard-command-key-in-fedora-like-system-with-mwm) (which is unanswered after 5 years). But I'd also really love to have <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for copy/paste movements while editing. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> would be great too.

Comment: @mazs Why did you make the links inaccessible?

Comment: @Anthon I didn't make them inaccessible, i made the word ubuntu to be the link 1 etc...

Comment: @mazs There was no text left below "Reference:", the references below that were gone, so the post ended in mid-air.

Comment: Also for clarification the standard keyboard shortcuts doesn't stop the original key-event. So while you can map ALT+S to CRTL+S the ALT+S event will still fire within that application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with Tweak Tool. Search in the overview (hit the *super* key, which probably has a Windows logo or is the Command key on a Mac keyboard; then type) for Tweak Tool and it'll either come up as installed or as install*able*.

In that tool, in the *Typing* panel, there are *a ton* of options, including swapping Control and Alt. (I like to make caps lock an additional control key, while I'm at it.)

Comment: Prefect! The extended explanation is sudo dnf install gnome-tweak-tool. Then access Tweek Tool. Typing > CTRL Key Position > Swap Left Alt with Left Control.